# Character reader (like FileReader) with dynamic repositioning based on characters offset

Tags: java, encoding

I am looking for something similar to a RandomAccessFile which would allow a positioning inside a big file based on the character (not the byte) offset, and allow reading from there. The FileReader or most implementations I came accross do not have a seek-like method such as the one provided in RandomAccessFile.

Does any such reader exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** No such `Reader` exists, because it can't easily be made to work with every encoding.

If the encoding you use is a fixed-width encoding (such as ISO-8859-*, a Windows codepage, ASCII, UCS-2, ...) then this could work, since you'd simply have to multiply the character offset by some constant (depending on the encoding, usually 1) to get the byte offset.

In fact you can easily emulate this yourself, by seeking on the underlying `InputStream` (make sure *not* to use a `BufferedReader`, since the buffering could be thrown off by the seeking).

But a couple of very popular encodings (and a few more less popular ones) are variable-width, meaning that each character can be represented by different numbers of bytes. UTF-8 and UTF-16 ones are well-known examples, but others like Shift-JIS have this property as well.

For variable-width encodings creating such a stream without any indexing or prior knowledge is not possible. One *could* implement the `seek()` by just reading the desired number of bytes, but that wouldn't actually have the benefit of a real `seek`, since you'd actually have to read the "skipped" bytes from disk to know how far to go.

Comment: Would this not be possible if you specify the encoding prior, even though it's a variable one like UTF-8?

Comment: @Blue_Elephant: just as with any sane reader, you'd definitely need know the encoding beforehand. But that doesn't solve the problem that "skip 5 characters" could require this code to skip anywhere between 5 and 20 bytes and there's no way to know without reading those bytes.

Comment: Does that mean that when you specify a byte offset, the time to position the file pointer there is about O(1)?

Comment: @Blue_Elephant: I'm not quite sure about O(1) (that really depends on the filesystem and storage medium), but seeking a million bytes into a file is **definitely** significantly faster than reading a million bytes of a file. For much smaller *n* this difference can become negligible (for example, seeking within the already cached data is probably only slightly faster than reading it).

Comment: I see. In fact the documentation for RandomAccessFile implies an array-like data structure it reads the bytes from ' _...There is a kind of cursor, or index into the implied array..._ '. This cannot be applied to a character stream, for reasons you mention in the answer.